# Windows Server - Using default rdp license of 2 while having many RDP sessions disconnected makes the RD services busy

Tags: windows, server, rdp

**Hi**

I want to test an application running in the background (of every logged in user) while users are logged in to the server using remote desktop but remote desktop session is disconnected.

My windows server 2016 is having the **default 2 license** for simultaneously connected users, which is all I need since I don't use more than 2 simultaneously connected users.

After ~15 login and disconnect, I start to experience a slowness while remote desktop of the next user.

Finally, it gets to a point where it takes very long time to connect and in some cases I get a message:

"The task you are trying to do can't be completed because remote desktop services is currently busy. please try again in a few minutes. Other users should still be able to log on."

Eventually, I manage to get my 150 users logged in to the server, but this behaviour is driving me crazy every time I need to test it again.

Is this behaviour something that Microsoft deliberately designed so I will have to use their license for multi users?

Again, I don't need simultaneously connected users...

Thanks,
Kobi

Answer (score 0):

To solve above problem one can restart term service for btw machine remotely. Trigger below commands to do the same:

(1.) tasklist /s \\servername /svc /fi “imagename eq svchost.exe” (locate PID for TermService)

(2.) taskkill /s \\servername /pid xxxx (may need /f to force, UAC might give problems as well)

(3.) sc \\servername start TermService

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following steps:

1. Login as Administrator
2. Open services.msc
3. Look for Remote Desktop Services
4. Right-click then click on Restart